# Do Inhabitiants Stick Around?

Tags: betrayal-legacy

If one Chapter introduces Inhabitiants but the next doesnt say they disappear, do the Inuabitiants stick around per chapter until the story tells us to remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Eventually, the Legacy deck will tell you during setup to place the existing inhabitants into the Tomb and replace them with new ones.

Bear in mind that if you kill an inhabitant, they get moved to the Tomb without the Legacy deck telling you to and do not appear in subsequent chapters.

**Do not destroy inhabitant cards unless the game explicitly tells you to** as they may be relevant to the game later.